# Problem Facing VMware Workstation Player in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: kernel, vmware-workstation

After installing vmware workstation in ubuntu 17.04, facing problems opening both, vmware player and vmware workstation. It seems problem in vmware kernel module updater and compiling several updater.
I tried many ways to solve but not worked. Sample of try are shown below:

## Trial 1:

sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

## Trial 2:

sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

## Trial 3

sudo apt-get install linux-generic

//after reboot

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

....................................

All trials gone failed, please give me anyone useful suggestion.